# "null" result of geocoder

Tags: android, reverse, reverse-geocoding

I have "null" result of geocoder function. I use geocoder to show address from latitide & longitude. this my part of code project.
how its fixed ?

goecoder code :

```
public void getMyLocationAddress() {
    Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {     
          //Place your latitude and longitude
          List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latMosque,lonMosque, 1);

        if(addresses != null) {

              Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
              StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

              for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
              }           
            lokasi ="lokasi : "+strAddress.toString();

          }   
          else
            lokasi = "lokasi tidak ditemukan";
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

code to show, use canvas, not xml..

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     Paint paint = mPaint;
    Paint paint5 =mPaint;
    paint5.setTextSize(20);
    paint5.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawText("Alamat : "+ lokasi , 50, 100, paint5);
 }
```

Comment: Do you *always* get null?

Comment: yes.. latitude and longitude detect automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [android.location.Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)). Quote from the documentation:

> Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

So perhaps your backend service is not available - or you are at a location it does not have data for.